# How to Parse a JSON response and group them date wise and head wise into a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, rest

This is the Sample response i am getting from the API.

```
{"success":true,"transaction":[{"_id":"58efd5717ddda769f26793fc","transId":"Exp/04-17/17","trpId":"Trav/dfsd/04-17/12","tripId":"58efd4dc7ddda769f26793f8","userId":"58ac19eaec1e7e4628be6f01","expenseHeadId":"588f279b85cd494eb7989c83","expenseHeadName":"Conveyance Expenses","transactionAmount":799,"isReimbursible":true,"paymentMode":"Cash","travelPurpose":"Official","hodId":"58aac3cb35c7194023da4777","clientId":"588f279b85cd494eb7989c80","fromCity":"Delhi","toCity":"Bhilai","fromCityId":"57f4aae6c0cd6b4cde54a514","toCityId":"583e0303e69a2e27ed7b416d","tripEndDate":"2017-04-27T18:30:00.000Z","policyDescription":"Not Applicable","expenseType":"general","__v":0,"hodApprovedTime":"2017-04-13T19:46:21.585Z","adminApprovedTime":"2017-04-13T19:47:55.910Z","accountsApprovedTime":"2017-04-13T20:07:30.097Z","paymentId":["58efda82f38d502c9e7fc5c1"],"isAccountsPaid":true,"isCancelled":false,"transactionStatus":"accounts-approved","isAccountsApproved":true,"isAdminApproved":true,"isHodApproved":true,"isDocUploaded":false,"createdTime":"2017-04-13T19:45:53.672Z"},{"_id":"58efd87af38d502c9e7fc5ba","transId":"Exp/04-17/18","trpId":"Trav/dfsd/04-17/12","tripId":"58efd4dc7ddda769f26793f8","userId":"58ac19eaec1e7e4628be6f01","expenseHeadId":"588f279b85cd494eb7989c85","expenseHeadName":"Travel","transactionAmount":1231,"isReimbursible":true,"paymentMode":"Draft","travelPurpose":"Official","hodId":"58aac3cb35c7194023da4777","clientId":"588f279b85cd494eb7989c80","fromCity":"Delhi","toCity":"Bhilai","fromCityId":"57f4aae6c0cd6b4cde54a514","toCityId":"583e0303e69a2e27ed7b416d","tripEndDate":"2017-04-27T18:30:00.000Z","policyDescription":"Not Applicable","expenseType":"general","__v":0,"hodApprovedTime":"2017-04-13T20:00:36.469Z","adminApprovedTime":"2017-04-13T20:00:53.898Z","accountsApprovedTime":"2017-04-13T20:03:39.801Z","paymentId":["58efd99bf38d502c9e7fc5bf"],"isAccountsPaid":true,"isCancelled":false,"transactionStatus":"accounts-approved","isAccountsApproved":true,"isAdminApproved":true,"isHodApproved":true,"isDocUploaded":false,"createdTime":"2017-04-13T19:58:50.678Z"}]}
```

What i a struggling in is how to display the data on the angular page as a table in which the row heads are the Dates and the Column Heads are the "expenseHeadName" in the response.

I have tried using a lot of different techniques nested loops and so on but so far nothing has worked satisfactorily.

For Example i would want table like this:

```
DATE        TRAVEL     FOOD   LODGING   TOTAL
15 Jun-2017    250       300     400       950
17 June 2017   300       200       0       500
```

My code till now (not sure if that will help)

```
angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) {

        var obj={};
       //var d=new Date(value.createdTime);


       // var d =value.createdTime;
        var d =new Date(value.createdTime);
         var d5 =d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var d6=new Date(d5);
         angular.forEach(response, function (value1, key1) {
             var d1=value1.createdTime;
             var d1 = new Date(d1);
            var d2 =d1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
             var d3=new Date(d2);
            if (d6.getTime() == d3.getTime()) 
            {
                obj['date']=d3;

                 angular.forEach(expenseHeadsArray, function (value, key) 
                        {
                            obj[value.expenseHeadName] = 0;

                        });
                obj['total']=0;
                rows.push(obj);

            }                 

         });
      // obj['date']=d.toDateString();

    });



    angular.forEach(rows, function (value_rows, key_rows) {
        angular.forEach(response, function (value_resp, key_resp) {
            var d1 = new Date(value_rows.date);
            var d2 = new Date(value_resp.createdTime);
            var d3 =d2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var d4=new Date(d3);
           // if (angular.equals(value_rows.date, value_resp.createdTime)) {
             if (d1.getTime() == d4.getTime()) {
                angular.forEach(expenseHeadsArray, function (value_expenseHead, key_expenseHead) {
                    if (angular.equals(value_resp.expenseHeadName, value_expenseHead.expenseHeadName)) {
                        var exhead=value_expenseHead.expenseHeadName;

                        rows[key_rows][exhead] += value_resp.transactionAmount;
                        rows[key_rows].total += value_resp.transactionAmount;
                }

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

My HTML Code:

```
<table class="table" id="expenses-report-table">
                                  <thead>
                                  <tr>

                                    <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in rows[0]">
                                      {{header | uppercase}}
                                    </th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                                    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
                                      {{cell }}
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Maybe i am missing out some easy link but any help would be appreciated.

I am using Angular .js on the frontend and Node.js on the backend

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: @NNR Have added the HTML

Comment: I couldn't find fields(Travel, Food, lodging) in your JSON response.

Comment: @NNR It would be under the "expenseHeadName" key in the JSON response. I have just given a sample for the example table. It could be named anything for that matter like in the one there is "Conveyance Expenses"

Comment: I made a sample example https://jsfiddle.net/vqJ5q/54/

Comment: I couldn't find those fields

Comment: @NNR I dont think you understood what i am trying to say. The field that you have hardcoded (ie the headers like food, travel etc) are dynamic and need to be pickedup from the "expenseHeadName" key.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found a way to show the table in a convincing manner. I hope it would help someone encountering the same problem.

I am using a counter so that a particular date is not repeated and again an array and a includes function so that there is no duplication.

```
var response1=[];
    var alreadydate=[];
    angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) 
                        {   
                            response1[key]=response[key];
                             var d =new Date(value.createdTime);
                            var d1 =d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                            var date = new Date(d1);
                            response1[key].createdTime=date;
                        });

    angular.forEach(response1, function (value, key) {

        var obj={};
       //var d=new Date(value.createdTime);


       // var d =value.createdTime;
        var d =new Date(value.createdTime);
         var d5 =d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var d6=new Date(d5);
        var counter =0;
         angular.forEach(response, function (value1, key1) {

             var d1=value1.createdTime;
             var d1 = new Date(d1);
            var d2 =d1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
             var d3=new Date(d2);
            if (d6.getTime() == d3.getTime()) 
            {
                obj['date']=d3;

                 angular.forEach(expenseHeadsArray, function (value, key) 
                        {
                            obj[value.expenseHeadName] = 0;

                        });
                obj['total']=0;
                if (counter==0 && !(alreadydate.includes(d2)) )
                    {
                         rows.push(obj);
                        counter ++;
                    }
                alreadydate.push(d2);


            }                 

         });
      // obj['date']=d.toDateString();

    });



    angular.forEach(rows, function (value_rows, key_rows) {
        angular.forEach(response, function (value_resp, key_resp) {
            var d1 = new Date(value_rows.date);
            var d2 = new Date(value_resp.createdTime);
            var d3 =d2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var d4=new Date(d3);
           // if (angular.equals(value_rows.date, value_resp.createdTime)) {
             if (d1.getTime() == d4.getTime()) {
                angular.forEach(expenseHeadsArray, function (value_expenseHead, key_expenseHead) {
                    if (angular.equals(value_resp.expenseHeadName, value_expenseHead.expenseHeadName)) {
                        var exhead=value_expenseHead.expenseHeadName;

                        rows[key_rows][exhead] += value_resp.transactionAmount;
                        rows[key_rows].total += value_resp.transactionAmount;
                }

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the code which works.